# Cookie authentication in ASP.Net core 2.0 Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I am trying to use cookie based authentication in ASP.Net Core 2.0 Web API and trying to activate that using the following code. The signin page is hosted inan separate domain than the one the app is hosted. And I have added `[Authorize]` attribute to the controller.

At startup I can see the service code invoked in debugger.

My expectation is that when my web client use the web api service, the middleware will detect that header does not have the cookie and will redirect the client to the login page. Yet I am able to invoke the controller freely.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
            services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
            builder => builder.SetIsOriginAllowed(s => true)
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowCredentials()));

        services.TryAddTransient<CorsAuthorizationFilter, CorsAuthorizationFilter>();

        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.OperationFilter<FileOperationFilter>();
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info
            {
                Title = "Collateral Management API",
                Version = "v1"
            });
        });

        services.AddMvcCore(options =>
            {

                options.Filters.Add(new CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory("AllowAll"));
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            })
            .AddApiExplorer()
            .AddJsonFormatters(s => s.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore);

        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(auth =>
            {
                auth.Cookie.Domain = "xxx.com";
                auth.Cookie.Name = "xxx";
                auth.LoginPath = "/signin";
                auth.AccessDeniedPath = "/signin";
            });

        services.AddAuthorization(auth =>
        {
            auth.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
        });
//...
}
```

and later ...

```
app.UseAuthentication()
```

Comment: Have you configured authorization?  The `LoginPath` will not be used unless the call is rejected by an authorization middleware later in the chain.

Comment: make sure app.UseAuthentication is before app.UseMvc. if testing on localhost then leave out the domain name. might also try make the cookie name the same as the authentication scheme

Comment: @Pace Could you please elaborate what you mean by configuring authorization - following your comment I also tried `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]` but that did not work either

Comment: I elaborated in an answer since it was a bit much for a comment.

Comment: Is it solved ? If not can you add the code of your middleware ? and the controller code ? Are you using IHttpContextAccessor in your controller constructor to access to your cookies ? If not you need to add it.

Answer (score 5):

Try adding:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
});
```

After `services.AddMvc()`

EDIT

Given the way you are adding MVC can you try:

```
// requires: using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
//           using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
services.AddMvcCore(config =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                     .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                     .Build();
    config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});
```

`AddMvcCore` doesn't add the authorization services by default. You will also need to do `AddMvcCore(...).AddAuthorization()`

Comment: Tried but did not work. I use  `services.AddMvcCore(options => options.Filters.Add(new CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory("AllowAll")))
                .AddApiExplorer()
                .AddJsonFormatters(s => s.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore);`

Comment: Added something else to try

Comment: I am getting exception now upon invoking an api `No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.IPolicyEvaluator' has been registered.` I edited my question to provide full relevant code in `ConfigureServices` I really appreciate that you continue toe assist me

Comment: I didn't realize that `AddMvcCore` doesn't add the authorization services by default.  You will need to do `AddMvcCore(...).AddAuthorization()`.

Comment: Thanks - the exception is gone - but the API is still not protected. Returns data just fine as before. I use `[Authorize]` attribute on the controller class.

Comment: Curious.  What happens if you comment out `services.AddAuthentication`?

Comment: No difference - API returns data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162448/discussion-between-anand-and-pace).

Comment: `AddMvcCore(...).AddAuthorization()` is what I needed with the policy being configured in the `AddMvcCore` builder method, not the `AddAuthorization`